# Change of scale $Y = aX+b$ to the mean of a test

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following problem:

The mean of a test is $6.25$ with a standard deviation of $1$. The teacher wants to change the scale such that the mean of the test is $7$ with a standard deviation of $0.8$. What change of scale of the type $Y=aX+b$ does the teacher need to do?

How can you change both the mean and the standard deviation?

Comment: $var(Y)=a^2 var(X)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve the system

$$\begin{cases}
a\cdot6.25+b=7 \\
a^2=0.64
\end{cases}$$

Thus

$$Y=0.8X+2$$

Comment: Thanks. Just one question, what if the standard deviation isn't $1$. Does it just multiplies the $b$?

Comment: @Rolando Gonzàles: if $\sigma \ne 1$ set $a^2\sigma^2=0 .64$